# Run migrations when deploying golang application to Heroku

Tags: go, heroku, migrate, go-modules

I've been trying to set up migrations for a golang application on Heroku. I'm using native Go modules (vgo) and the official Heroku build pack. For migrations I'm using the [migrate](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate) package.

The thing is, I could run migrations when the main function runs, but it feels a bit hacky, this would mean that every time the app restarts it will run the migrations. I would prefer to just run the schema migration when deploying.

I'm not sure how this can be accomplished, when I log in to the instance the go binary is not installed, it's like the build pack only executes the main function.

I could live with doing it with a Heroku CLI command but I can't find how to do this in the docs nor via Google.

Comment: What tool are you using for your migrations? [goose](https://github.com/steinbacher/goose)? Is `goose` in an interactive `heroku run` session?

Comment: That should be "Is `goose` _available_ in an interactive `heroku run` session."

Comment: You're right, forgot to add that. I'm using [migrate](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate) @Chris . In an interactive session I don't really have the migrate command, I'm also not doing anything special for it to be available though, that's what I would like to know how to do

Answer (score 1):

All of your dependencies should be defined such that Heroku can install them for you. For Go, Heroku supports [godep](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/go-dependencies-via-godep) and [govendor](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/go-dependencies-via-govendor). If you're not already using one, pick one and start.

Your dependency file should be committed to your repository. For godep that's `Godeps/Godeps.json` and for govendor it's `vendor/vendor.json`. Your dependencies themselves should *not* be committed.

After you've added a dependency on `migrate` it should be available on Heroku. You can run `migrate up` and other commands via `heroku run bash`. Once you're comfortable running migrations manually you might want to consider adding a [release phase command](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase) to your `Procfile` so migrations get applied automatically when you deploy a new version.